# How to connect window device with android studio / vscode running on virtual machine for flutter desktop application?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I am trying to develop a window application using flutter. My host os is linux. So, I have installed virtualbox and installed windows in that and changed the network adapter to bridged network. Now, I am able to ping the window machine using windows ip, which is 192.168.43.173, Now I want to use the windows machine for the application development.
I thought doing this will show the window device in the flutter device list. What should I do so that I can connect and develop the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter has no support for what you are trying to do:

- Cross-compiling is not currently supported for desktop; you cannot build for Windows from a Linux host.
- The only desktop target device that is currently supported is the host itself; you cannot build on one machine and install and run on another from the `flutter` tool.

You will need to do your development from within your virtual machine.